# How to log exception details in Spring AOP with try with empty catch block?

Tags: spring, exception, spring-aop

Log exception details in Spring AOP with empty catch block. 
For example:

```
  try {
        int data = 50 / 0;

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Exception not printing stack trace in spring aop for empty catch methods

I am using "@AfterThrowing" but its not working. Please find below code:

@AfterThrowing(pointcut ="catsServiceLevelLog()",throwing = "ex")

public void exceptionAdvice(Throwable ex) throws Throwable
{

}

Comment: why you want to use emty catch block

Comment: In existing code, some methods having this code and i want to enable all this exception details in logger using Spring AOP Configuration.

Comment: I am using @AfterThrowing but its not working.

Comment: I very much doubt this is possible, since that would only be able to be bound at runtime, while the parameters are bound at compile time